# Extracting data between tags from huge text (XML) files

Tags: xml, tags, extract

Note: I'm on a Windows 7, 64 bit system - just installed cygwin.

I need to extract large amounts of data from a lot of different large (100s of MB) XML files.   The xml files contain a bunch of sequences of lines that looks like:

```
<taggie>
lotsolines which include some string that I'm searching for.
</taggie>
```

I want to extract everything from the start tag to the end tag that contains the search string.  (It's a toss-up whether to do this in python or a script in cygwin.)

My plan is to write a script to preprocess out a table of begin and end tags from one of these xml files and create a reference table of line numbers for the begin-end. 
Something like

```
filename, start line (begin tag), end line (end tag)
bogusname.xml, 50025, 100003
```

Then I do another search to create a list of where my strings occur.
It will look maybe something like this.

```
filename, searchstring, line number
bogusname.xml, "foo", 76543
```

Then I process this second list against the first list, to extract the info (maybe into a second huge file or maybe into a set of files. I don't care at this point.

Anyway it occurs to me while I'm doing this that someone has almost certainly done this exact thing or something very similar to it.

So, can anyone direct me to code that already does this?  Python preferred, but a unix style script for cygwin would be handy. I prefer source code to any executable where I can't see what the source is doing.

Meanwhile, I'm proceeding on my own. Thanks in advance.

For the exact data, I'm downloading this file (for example):
http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2015/ipg150106.zip
I unzip it and I want to extract those XML documents that contain any of a large number of search strings. This is a single file with thousands of concatenated XML documents. I want to extract any XML that contains one of the search strings.

I'm experimenting with BeautifulSoup at the moment:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # To get everything
import urllib2

xml_handle = open("t.xml", "r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_handle)

i = 0
for grant in soup('us-patent-grant'):
    i = i + 1
    print (i)
    print (grant)

print (i)
```

When I do this, it gives a final value for i of 9.
If it were getting ALL of the 'us-patent-grant' tags, I would expect i to be well over 6000 - which indicates to me that it may not be parsing the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(past answer)

what about using python package beautifulsoup? plus regular expression. BeautifulSoup is the most famous tool for dealing with .html, .xml file. 
import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
f = open("filename.xml")
xml = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
find_search = re.compile("[search]+")
#remain code here....
```

check this website http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ for beautifulsoup,
and https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for regular expression grammar.

but you can easily do what you want after visiting this web page.

======================================================================

The file is too big, so you need some codes to split files into seperate files. From the link [Split diary file into multiple files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860441/split-diary-file-into-multiple-files-using-python), you can write your code as

```
<!-- language: python -->
def files():
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        yield open('xml_%d.xml' % n, 'w')
pat = '<?xml'
fs = files()
outfile = next(fs) 
with open("ipg150106.xml") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if pat not in line:
            outfile.write(line)
        else:
            items = line.split(pat)
            outfile.write(items[0])
            for item in items[1:]:
                outfile = next(fs)
                outfile.write(pat + item)
```

This code gives me to xml_6527.xml.

```
def files():
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        yield open('xml_%d.xml' % n, 'w')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #make file seperate
    # pat = '<?xml'
    # fs = files()
    # outfile = next(fs) 

    # with open("ipg150106.xml") as infile:
    #     for line in infile:
    #         if pat not in line:
    #             outfile.write(line)
    #         else:
    #             items = line.split(pat)
    #             outfile.write(items[0])
    #             for item in items[1:]:
    #                 outfile = next(fs)
    #                 outfile.write(pat + item)

    #analyzing each file
    import os
    pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    xml_files = [xml_file for xml_file in os.listdir(pwd) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(pwd, xml_file))]

    for f in xml_files:
        xml = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
        #Remain code here..
```

(sorry for strange code block :( )

Comment: I'm looking at that right now.  The issue I'm having with it is that each one of these huge files contains thousands of concatenated XML documents - and I'm not sure, but I think BS is only reading the first one.  Looking through docs now.

Comment: @elbillaf I once scrapped one facebook group page about nearly 50000 posts including comments, but the beautifulsoup scrapped it and parsed it within 10 seconds on my 4GB ram macbook. Plus, I suggest what about seperating concatenated XML documents?

Comment: I don' t know what you suggest.

Comment: @elbillaf what about using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717294/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-pattern-cut-can-occur-within-lines ?
Split a lot of xml file first, and then use beautifulsoup for each file, then write into one output file.

Comment: Breaking it up works.  That's good. I can work with this. thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on a similar problem in Python. I know that this is a few years late, but I'll share my experiences parsing similarly large files.

I found that Python's builtin, [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) works quite well for this (the C implementation of this, called cElementTree has the same API and is also builtin).  I tried every approach in the docs, and [iterparse() with clear()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#functions) was by far the fastest in the library (x5 faster than any other implementation I made in Python).  This approach allows you to incrementally load and clear xml to and from memory, processing it as a stream (using a generator).  This is much better than loading a whole file into memory, which will likely slow your computer to a crawl.

**References:**

[The accepted answer here explains basically the best approach that I could find.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324214/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-parse-large-xml-docs-in-python)

[This IBM site talks about lxml which is similar to the xml library but has better XPath support.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/index.html)

The [lxml website](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm) and [cElementTree website](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm) comparing execution speeds of xml and lxml packages.